# How to include javascript library in xaringan/remark.js?

Tags: xaringan, remarkjs

I'm working on a presentation using xaringan, and am using a few gifs created by gganimate to illustrate some points about a model. It works great, except that once the gifs start playing they just keep playing, and sometimes they seem to start playing before I get to their slide.

I would like to be able to explicitly start and stop each gif, and the solution seems to be the [giffer](https://github.com/krasimir/gifffer) javascript library, but here is where I fall far short of "ninja" status. How do I install and load the giffer library for use by xaringan. I suspect it's somewhere in the YAML, possibly `include`, but that's as far as I've gotten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include javascript in the YAML by

```
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    nature:
      beforeInit: ["gifffer.min.js", "load.js"]
```

as mentioned [here](https://slides.yihui.name/xaringan/#34).

Here `load.js` just contains

```
window.onload = function() {
  Gifffer();
}
```

but you can change the settings, styling of button etc as described in [gifffer](https://github.com/krasimir/gifffer).